# how can i get 1dimension to 3dimension reshape?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm

here is my code

```
def create_dataset(signal_data, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(signal_data) - look_back):
        dataX.append(signal_data[i:(i + look_back), 0])
        dataY.append(signal_data[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

look_back = 20
...

train_size = int(len(data) * 0.80)

test_size = len(data) - train_size

train = data[0:train_size]

test = data[train_size:len(data)]

x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)

x_test, y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)
```

then `x_train` shape is (62796, 20) and `y_train` shape is(62796,)

I use this data to LSTM

so, reshape `x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))` is done

(now `x_train.shape` is (62796, 20, 1) )

but `y_train` shape is (62796,) So, i can't reshape 1D -> 3D

how can i `y_train` reshape 1D ->3D

i want y_train shape as (62796, 20, 1) because want to LSTM `return_sequences=True` parameter

Comment: Of course you can not reshape (62796,) array to (62796, 20, 1) array since you have less values to reshape. If you want to get (62796, 20, 1) array, you have to repeat your values in (62796,) array by some way you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
y_train = np.ones(100)
print(y_train.shape) #prints (100,)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,1,1)
print(y_train.shape) # prints (100,1,1)
```

EDIT: Final solution, after brief discussion in comments:

```
y_train=np.repeat(y_train.reshape(-1,1), 20, axis=1).reshape(-1,20,1)
```

Comment: no, LSTM input is ```x = (batch_size, timesteps, features)```
and ```y(batch_size, timesteps, numb_outputs)```, so i want y shape (62796, 20, 1) but if i ```y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 20, 1)``` then ```ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 62796 into shape (20,1)``` occur

Comment: so you want these 62796 values to be repeated 20 times? Is that correct?

Comment: then try `y_train = np.tile(y_train, 20).reshape(-1,20,1)`

Comment: actually, command given in my previous comment is not giving what I thought it would - here's fix: `y_train=np.repeat(y_train.reshape(-1,1), 20, axis=1).reshape(-1,20,1)`